# How to do code review for Twitter Bootstrap Projects?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Creating a plan to do the code review in designing team for bootstrap projects to decrease the defects and to improve the quality.

Drafted some questions for the code review checklist, which is pasted below.

**What more questions can be included in this checklist OR points to check against developer's code to ensure the quality of the code?**

1. bootstrap.css is not modified?
2. Chosen plugins that make sense and required
3. Showing multiple modal prompts is avoided
4. Placed modal's HTML just before  or right after
5. Followed the naming conventions of bootstrap?
6. The latest version of bootstrap got used?
7. Used the container-fluid class for full-width rows instead of a full-width row?
8. Are you using the correct Media Query Break Points according to bootstrap CSS?
9. Bootstrap grid used to make a design responsive?

These checklist questions are not yet complete and need your guidance and help to do the full code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bootstrap is design as a mobile first approach so you should always check whether the mobile first approach has been followed or not.
2. Bootstrap is a huge library so you should check whether all the components have been properly used or not. Eg. there are many components like `accordion, panels, carousel` are there which can make your design compact and look good.
3. Check whether all the columns are wrapped inside `<div class="row"></div>` or not because that's the proper way of using bootstrap.
4. Check whether the bootstrap `cdns` are being used twice in a page or not. reason, if use include bootstrap `cdns` twice in a pge that will interfere with the proper functioning of some elements.

the following should be the order of bootstrap `cdns`--

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

These are some basic things that you should check while doing the review.

**EDIT**

**For performance**

Checkout this answer https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52502/how-can-i-speed-up-the-download-time-of-a-bootstrap-themed-website

**Documentation**

[The Official website](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com)

Many other documentation is available online.[check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/info)

**coding standards**

Now for me that's a relative term and changes according to need.

**Note**

just a suggestion from my personal point-view, don't be too rigid regarding the rules while reviewing. If a piece of code seems wrong apparently but solves a problem gracefully I would accept that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really helpful. Yes, this would also help me to review further for the points which you have mentioned in your answer so as to make code more efficient. Can we add some checklist points related to the Performance, Coding Standards, Documentation, etc. along with what not to do for better code?